# Java - Command Line on Linux: I don't have any output after I run the code

Tags: java, linux, command-line, javac, cplex

I am a beginner user of command-line. I use Eclipse for my optimization problem with cplex.jar on my computer. Since my computer is not enough for big problems, I try to use the school Linux server. I finally found a code piece that works without an error. However, after I run this, I don't see anything(solving something etc). Could you please help me to understand why I see nothing after this?

Before this code, I had many errors about my java files, my argument, jar file etc.

```sh
javac -source "1.8" -cp ".:./PDP-TWT2/cplex.jar" PDP-TWT2/src/MainPDP2.java PDP-TWT2/src/Node.java PDP-TWT2/src/Vehicle.java PDP-TWT2/src/Arc.java < "PDP-TWT2/Param.txt"
```

When I run my code, I see the following in Eclipse. I believe this is what I supposed to see in the server right?

```
 **************************************************.
Warning:  Output names have been modified to conform to LP format.
Tried aggregator 2 times.
MIP Presolve eliminated 1604 rows and 96 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 244 coefficients.
Aggregator did 180 substitutions.
Reduced MIP has 3299 rows, 1970 columns, and 11256 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 1942 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 0.01 sec. (11.67 ticks)
Probing fixed 12 vars, tightened 0 bounds.
```

...Many other similar lines...

```
        Nodes                                         Cuts/
   Node  Left     Objective  IInf  Best Integer    Best Bound    ItCnt     Gap

      0     0       35.5800    72                     35.5800      891         
      0     0       36.3600    90                    Cuts: 68     1290         
      0     0       36.3600   102                    Cuts: 68     1644
```

Comment: `javac` only compiles your code. It doesn't run it. You need to use the `java` command-line program to run the compiled code.

Comment: Assuming `MainPDP2.java` conatains the `main` function, you might have to run something like `java -cp ".:./PDP-TWT2/cplex.jar" PDP-TWT2/src/MainPDP2.class < "PDP-TWT2/Param.txt"`.

Comment: Thank you @byxor! It was helpful but not enough for now. Yes, @Bodo! This is where main function included. Whenever I run java, I am getting a version problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first compile and then execute the application. Assuming that you have `src` directory with sources and `out` directory for compiled classes:

```
$ cd PDP-TWT2
$ javac -source 1.8 -d ./out src/**/*.java
```

and then execute the class containing the `main()` method:

```
$ cd out
$ java MainPDP2 < ../Param.txt
```

Checkout [Essentials, Part 1, Lesson 1: Compiling & Running a Simple Program](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/compile-136656.html) if want to learn more. If you are using Java 11 this whole process is simplified with [JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330).

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. No, I don't have any out folder. I have a Project folder called "PDP-TWT2", 2 subfolders src(includes java files) and bin(includes class files). Thank you for differentiating javac and java for me! That was quite helpful. Still, I have an issue when I deleted < "..Param.txt". And, is it normal that the same code works sometimes and sometimes doesn't? Whenever I use "java PDP-TWT2/bin/MainPDP2", I am getting error about version even I set it to 1.8 in javac.